# How to get return value from a Diesel sql function

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I have a SQL function (in Postgres) that I'd like to call using Diesel. I've declared it using the `sql_function!` macro, and I can call the function OK. But I'm not able to get the return value — it always returns `1`, which I'm assuming is a row count. How can I get the actual return value?

```rust
sql_function! {
    fn my_add(a: Int4, b: Int4) -> Int4;
}

let my_add_fn = my_add(2, 4);
let result = diesel::select(my_add_fn).execute(&conn).unwrap();
dbg!(&result); // This prints 1. Should be 6
```

When I call `my_add` from the Postgres CLI, it works correctly:

```
select my_add(2, 4);
 my_add 
--------
      6
(1 row)
```

And here is the `my_add` function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_add(
    a integer,
    b integer
)
    RETURNS integer
AS $$
BEGIN
    return a + b;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
    IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: "When asking the database to return data from a query, load should probably be used instead." https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/query_dsl/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#method.execute

Comment: @Stargateur — Thanks, this worked: `diesel::select(my_add_fn).first(&conn)`. (Where `first` and `load` are pretty similar.) If you want to write it up as a full answer, I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question but figured I'd post a response in case anyone else lands here.

When you call `execute` as you did, what you're returned is only the number of affected rows. **See**: [getting started guide](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started.html), and search for `"get_result"`. In a `select`, `load` is probably the best choice, as a comment already noted - ([docs](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/query_dsl/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#method.load)).

To get back the result(s) from an `insert` or `update` query, replace `execute` with `get_result` or `get_results` for multiple rows (which will give you back a `Vec<T>` instead of just `T`) ... more [docs](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/query_dsl/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#method.get_result).